# Unable to import specific entry points for Angular Materials since the update on Angular 8

Tags: angular

I found out here: [Angular changelog](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) that version 8 now requires specific entry points for importing.

However, I keep getting an error unless I downgrade the version of "@angular/cdk" & "@angular/material" in the package.json.

I understand that I can just use this command `ng update @angular/material & ng update @angular/cli @angular/core` to issue the update. But is giving me an error

> Cannot find module 'rxjs'

I have also updated my node node to version 12.

To simplify things, here is a very simply sample code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/exercise-basic-c-v3).

Here, I just added the dependency "@Angular/Material" and imported `import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';` in the app module to display a simple toolbar.

Although the error produced is different, I believe knowing how to properly import will solve the issue.

Comment: have you tried to do "npm i" first?

Comment: Also before upgrade to 8 did you use v7?

Comment: I also did npm install. And yes, I used v7. But you can just focus on the sample code I provided as the issue is most likely the same.

Comment: Does your package json has rxjs?

Comment: Your blitz has incompatible versions...

Comment: What version are you actually referring to? The Stackblitz's @angular/cdk and @angular/material has both version 8 (latest). My question is, how do you simply import Angular Material.